# T-SQL SELECT top Category by LastUpdateDateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want a more elegant way to select the top category in the table below by LastUpdatedDateTime descending.  Basically I only want to see the latest single row for each Category by CategoryID.

I can get that by doing the following...

```
SELECT Category,
   MAX(LastUpdateDateTime) as LastUpdateDateTime
INTO #t
FROM Settings
WHERE CatalogID = 123
GROUP BY Category
ORDER BY Category

SELECT s.*
FROM Settings s
INNER JOIN #t t
ON s.Category = t.Category
AND s.LastUpdateDateTime = t.LastUpdateDateTime
```

--> Settings table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Settings](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CatalogID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Category] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Facings] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Quantity] [bit] NOT NULL,
[LastUpdateDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Settings_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
[ID] ASC,
[CatalogID] ASC,
[Category] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is pretty simple, just looking for someone to point me in the right direction to do this a little more efficiently.  What I have WORKS.  I want to refactor please.

Thanks for looking.

-B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a sub-query:

```
select s1.*
from settings s1
inner join
(
  select category, max(LastUpdateDateTime) as LastUpdateDateTime
  from settings
  where catalogid = 123
  group by category
) s2
  on s1.category = s2.category
  and s1.LastUpdateDateTime = s2.LastUpdateDateTime
```

or even use CTE:

```
;with cte as
(
  select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by catalogid 
                      order by LastUpdateDateTime desc) rn
  from settings
  where catalogid = 123
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I think the ROW_NUMBER() solution is better, in case of a possible tie on LastUpdateDateTime. Also, if you use the * like this, you'll get the rn column in your results (I realize this was probably just done to keep it simple and compact).

Comment: @GilM I used `select *` because that is what the OP had, but typically I would specify each column need in the `SELECT`. :)

Comment: @bluefeet, the first suggestion works great!  The suggestion with Common Table Expressions intrigues me but it only returned one row.  Any idea why?  I have 5 distinct rows I was expecting from my data set.

Comment: @brianhevans without seeing any sample data, I cannot be sure what the issue is. feel free to create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with a working data model for me to test with.

Comment: @bluefeet, I modified the cte partition to look at Category, which is what changes and I got the result I was looking for!  Thanks for the speedy reply.